# PostGIS: Update table with st_geometryfromtext

Tags: postgis, postgresql, update, syntax, well-known-binary

I'm trying to update a column `wkb_geometry` in a table `locations` by creating a point from the `eastings` and `northings` cols from the same table. The database is `PostGreSQL` with `PostGIS` extension:

```
UPDATE locations
SET wkb_geometry = st_geometryfromtext('POINT(locations.easting locations.northing)',2770);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
SQL state: XX000
Hint: "POINT(lo" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
```

The column has been added like this:

```
ALTER TABLE locations ADD COLUMN wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,27700);
```

I suspect that `locations.easting` and `locations.northing` are not being substituted with actual values from the respective columns but am not sure how to fix this. The answer I'm after will show how to substitute the easting and northing string with actual values from the column

Comment: ST_GeomeyryFromText requires input in Well Known Text (WKT) format, which you are not providing. ST_MakePoint does not (but it requires an ST_SetSRID)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a string, so it can't substitute the values from your columns. You have to concatenate the string:

```
UPDATE locations
SET wkb_geometry = st_geometryfromtext('POINT('|| easting ||' '|| northing ||')',27700);
```

Answer (score 5):

As nunatak points out, you're not correctly substituting your values within the string.  However, you can avoid string substitution altogether by using
http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html
e.g.

```
UPDATE locations
SET wkb_geometry = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(locations.easting,locations.northing),27700);
```

Note from the postgis docs

> ST_MakePoint while not being OGC compliant is generally faster and
>   more precise than ST_GeomFromText and ST_PointFromText. It is also
>   easier to use if you have raw coordinates rather than WKT.

I'd always promote using Makepoint over text representation for speed and readability; and you can see using string concatenation etc. ends up looking very messy.

Comment: Agreed, the `ST_MakePoint` method makes it clearer where the values are coming from. I suppose the end result is the same though? I'll be using the wkb_geometry column to retrieve records within a given bounding box

Comment: The result may well be the same. However, advantages of using the ST_MakePoint include (1) being faster and (2) lending itself to any type checking you may have available